# for data in json_dictionary: # Loop through dictionary keys NameError: name 'json_dictionary' is not defined

Tags: python, json, decode, payload

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):  # The callback for when a message is received from the server.      
    json_string = str(msg.payload)
    json_dictionary = json.loads(json_string)  # Load JSON string to a dictionary


for data in json_dictionary:  # Loop through dictionary keys
    print(data, ":", json_dictionary[data])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please format your question with the proper syntax.  If the ```for data...``` loop is outside the def, then ```json_dictionary``` isn't available to it.  You either define json_dictionary as a global or you return the json_dictionary variable to the main scope.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for your help.  I am really appreciative . Im new to Python and I really do not understand your response.  That is my short coming, not yours, but I will research your reply, and I'm sure I'll sort it.  Regards

Comment: I dont know what the proper syntax is.

Answer (score 2):

It gives an error as `json_dictionary` is inside the function. You need to either return or declare `json_dictioanry` and then call the function `on_message`.
Try in this way:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):  # The callback for when a message is received from the server.
    json_string = str(msg.payload)
    json_dictionary = json.loads(json_string)  # Load JSON string to a dictionary
    return json_dictionary

json_dictionary = on_message(client,userdata,msg)
for data in json_dictionary.keys():
    print(data, ":", json_dictionary[data])
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  Now it’s telling me ‘client’ is not define.

Comment: You need to assign a value to `client` before calling the function. What is the value you intended to pass to the function?

Comment: Just want to say thank you for your help here.  I have it going perfectly.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if you found it helpful